# pip install lxml error

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, lxml

I am aware that this question was asked many times. I have tried all known recipes but still have a problem.

So, I have created clear environment. Then `pip install lxml` with an error:

```
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/libxml2 -Isrc/lxml/includes -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/lxml/lxml.etree.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o -w

In file included from src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:85:0:

/usr/include/python2.7/Python.h:8:22: fatal error: pyconfig.h: No such file or directory

compilation terminated.

Compile failed: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

creating tmp

cc -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/libxml2 -c /tmp/xmlXPathInitRwrJxg.c -o tmp/xmlXPathInitRwrJxg.o

/tmp/xmlXPathInitRwrJxg.c:2:1: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Wimplicit-int]

 main (int argc, char **argv) {

 ^

cc tmp/xmlXPathInitRwrJxg.o -lxml2 -o a.out

error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /home/andriy/PROJECTS/delete/env/bin/python2 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-XHiH0Y/lxml/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-zuYS3W-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/andriy/PROJECTS/delete/env/include/site/python2.7 failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-XHiH0Y/lxml
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/andriy/PROJECTS/delete/env/bin/pip", line 11, in <module>
sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/andriy/PROJECTS/delete/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 248, in main
    return command.main(cmd_args)
  File "/home/andriy/PROJECTS/delete/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 161, in main
    text = '\n'.join(complete_log)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 68: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I should say that I have successfully installed `lxml` on environment with Python3. Moreover, I have already been successfully installing `lxml` package to other environments earlier. But now something broke.

Any ideas how to solve it with Python2.7?

It is the second day of torments and I am about to reinstall my Ubuntu.

**SOLUTION**

Below **Padraic Cunningham** solved my problem. Log directly indicates that the problem is caused by the absence of file `pyconfig.h` in the system. It is the file of `python-dev` package. However, this package was already installed. So, it is naturally to assume that the package is corrupter and should be reinstalled with `sudo apt-get install  --reinstall python-dev libpython2.7-dev`. Additionally `libpython2.7-dev` was reinstalled. After that file `pyconfig.h` appeared in correct place and `pip install lxlm` successfully installed the `lxml` package.

Comment: Make sure you have `python-dev` installed

Comment: Hope somebody will come up with some unknown recipe.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham It is already installed.

Comment: So `ls /usr/include/python2.7/ | grep pyconfig` returns something?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham No, it doesn't... Should it? But `dpkg --get-selections | grep python-dev` among others returns me `libpython-dev:amd64    install` and `python-dev     install`

Comment: Yes, it should be there, just to verify `sudo apt-get install libpython2.7-dev`

Comment: omg... I suppose, I know what caused the problem. Two weeks ago I was trying to delete all `*.pyc` files. I suppose, I have deleted also files containing `pyc` in their names and `pyconfig` was one of them.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Unfortunately, `sudo apt-get install libpython2.7-dev` was unsuccessful. System answered **libpython2.7-dev is already the newest version.** Could you help me now, when we know what exactly caused the problem?

Comment: try `sudo apt-get --reinstall install python-dev libpython2.7-dev`

Comment: http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/libpython2.7-dev/filelist you can see the `pyconfig.h` file listed so if it installed it has to be somewhere, what does `locate pyconfig.h` return?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Reinstall of `python-dev` and `libpython2.7-dev` solved the problem! I managed to install `lxml` in environment! Thank you! Please make your comment as an answer I could mark it as a solution.

Answer (score 1):

u can try it:

`sudo apt-get install python-dev libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev zlib1g-dev`

Comment: already installed.