# Getting error while trying "pip install python-docx" in pycharm terminal

Tags: python-docx

New to python and just trying pip install python-docx and getting this message:

Command "C:\Users\samue\PycharmProjects\testings\venv\Scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file
__='C:\Users\samue\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_4bceyq4\lxml\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open
)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record
C:\Users\samue\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-pg5bpdaa\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --com
error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\Hos
tX86\x86\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

```
----------------------------------------
```

Command "C:\Users\samue\PycharmProjects\testings\venv\Scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users
\samue\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_4bceyq4\lxml\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().re
place('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\samue\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-reco
rd-pg5bpdaa\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers C:\Users\samue\PycharmProjects\te
stings\venv\include\site\python3.8\lxml" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\samue\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_4bceyq4\lxml
\

Answer (score 0):

When you install with pip you use the command pip and not python.

To see whether pip is correctly installed type:

```
pip help
```

See the following page for how to install and configure pip on Windows:

```
https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-pip-windows
```

Your error output shows a problem with lxml. Looking into it I have found the page   [pip install lxml error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36017879/pip-install-lxml-error)  which suggests the following solution:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-dev libpython2.7-dev.
```

Comment: Hey Kendle, Thanks for your help. "pip help" working fine. Maybe something else?